# Framework similar to electronJS for developing cross-platform mobile apps

Tags: javascript, mobile, frameworks, electron, cross-platform

Just like we have `electronJS` for developing cross-platform desktop applications, what do we have for cross-platform mobile app development? Are there any frameworks which are also using `Javascript`, `CSS`, `HTML`, `nodeJS` etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to have a look at `React Native` which is used to build cross-platform mobile applications. It is developed by Facebook.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/